# How to declare an object of arrays of custom type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am searching how to declare a variable where I can store users by birthdate while avoiding using any

```
let formatedUsers = {} as "TYPE_NEEDED"
  for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    const user= users[i];
    if (!formatedUsers[user.birthdate]) formatedUsers[user.birthdate] = [];
    formatedUsers[user.birthdate].push(user);
  }
```

In the end I want my variable "formatedUsers" to be like this:

```
formatedUsers = {
12-02-1996: [user1, user3, user4],
02-04-1998: [user2],
05-08-1999: [user5, user6]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object keys are strings, and the object values are arrays of users, so a relatively simple Record will do it. Assuming you have a reference to the type of `user`, you can do:

```
const formattedUsers: Record<string, User[]> = [];
```

If you don't have a reference to the user type, you can extract it first.

```
type User = (typeof users)[number];
```

Comment: date should also be typed, not just string.

Comment: Thank you it works, how can I change your answer to accept Date instead of string if I need to?

Comment: Object keys cannot be dates. Object keys may only be strings, numbers, or Symbols. If you want to have a Date object as a "key", use a Map instead. `Map<Date, User[]>`

Comment: could there be any checking on date string such as `12-02-1996`?

Comment: @ABOS Only if the date string is manually constructed - see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70929542/9515207) for how to type it - but that's likely to require a decent amount of additional code for no real type benefit IMO

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you can use the Record interface.

```
let formatedUsers: Record<number, User[]> = {0:[]};
```

You can also initialize the value like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is more accurate since it requires keys to be `number-number-number`

```
const formattedUsers: Record<`${number}-${number}-${number}`, User[]> = {};
```